# R create column from another column, depending on row

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking to find a way to create a new column "signup". This column takes the value of column *2* where column *1* == "c". And that must be done for each user_id.

```
user_id    1       2       count
1          a    21/01/2016  2
1          a    1/02/2016   2
1          b    1/12/2015   6
1          b    14/12/2015  6
1          b    1/12/2015   6
1          b    1/12/2015   6
1          b    14/12/2015  6
1          b    1/12/2015   6
1          c    10/12/2015  1
```

Result would be something like that:

```
user_id    1       2       count    signup
1          a    21/01/2016  2        10/12/2015
1          a    1/02/2016   2        10/12/2015
1          b    1/12/2015   6        10/12/2015
1          b    14/12/2015  6        10/12/2015
1          b    1/12/2015   6        10/12/2015
1          b    1/12/2015   6        10/12/2015
1          b    14/12/2015  6        10/12/2015
1          b    1/12/2015   6        10/12/2015
1          c    10/12/2015  1        **10/12/2015**
```

**NOTE:** For each *user_id*, there is only one row such that column *2* is equal to "c".

I am currently learning data.table so I have preference for a solution that uses that package. Any solution, however, is appreciated.

Comment: Try `setDT(df1)[, signup :=  X2[X1 == 'c'], by = user_id]
`

Comment: perfect! Did not know qbout setDT. Thank you